# Ruby & Datamapper checking if a record exists, and where?

Tags: ruby, oauth, sinatra, datamapper

I have a basic Ruby app that I am building with Sinatra, Datamapper and has user authentication using OAuth. When I receive the data back from the Oauth service, I save a record of a new user in an sqlite3 db.

What I don't know how to do is how to go about verifying the user record doesn't already exist on the user database table. I can use the user's unique id (uid) to cross check whether the uid is already stored, but I am just unsure where to do this.

I have 2 classes and a **/callback** route. The **User** class is the db model, and an **Authentication** class has assorted methods for connecting to the OAuth, and the **/callback** route which will have the Authentication.save method being called.

Should I be checking for an existing record within the **Authentication.save** method and return a boolean or something else? Create a new method in **Authentication** that would be like Authentication.exists? (and what would that look like?) Or should I be checking within the **/callback** route?

I apologize if this wasn't 100% clear, I am having a difficult time describing my issue and am an absolute Ruby beginner...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just before creating your new user, you should try to check if an user with the same login and email (for example) exists :

```
require 'dm-aggregates'

user=User.new
user.login=your_login_data_returned_by_oauth
user.email=your_email_data_returned_by_oauth
# And so on...
user.save if User.count(:login=>user.login, :email=>user.email) == 0
```

Comment: I'm not sure but it looks like to, potentially, fetch a whole full filled collection of objects to check the existence of a register is not an optimized solution. I'll replace the condition with `if User.count(:login=>user.login, :email=>user.email) == 0`.

Comment: The User.count is better, I don't know why I didn't mention it as it is the way I always do that sort of things.

Comment: On a second thought , user.count doesnt work : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393004/ruby-datamapper-count-not-working  . I got bitten by it as well