# Ruby Datamapper count not working

Tags: ruby, sinatra, ruby-datamapper

From irb when I do:

```
Router.all(:email=>"blake@gmail.com")
```

I get a list of all the routers associated with that email. But when I do:

```
Router.count(:email=>"blake@gmail.com")
```

I always get 0

I've also looked at this question: [Ruby Datamapper .count always returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548032/ruby-datamapper-count-always-returns-0) but I still don't know why it isn't working.

-- Update #1 --

Here is the output of the Router.all command. As you can see I get results back.

```
1.9.3-p362 :003 > Router.all(:email=>"blake@gmail.com")
=> [#<Router @id=8 @email="blake@gmail.com" @hostname="router0">, #<Router @id=9              @email="blake@gmail.com" @hostname="router0">, #<Router @id=10 @email="blake@gmail.com" @hostname="router0">, #<Router @id=11 @email="blake@gmail.com" @hostname="router0">, #<Router @id=13 @email="blake@gmail.com" @hostname="router0">, #<Router @id=14 @email="blake@gmail.com" @hostname="router0">, #<Router @id=15 @email="blake@gmail.com" @hostname="router0">, #<Router @id=16 @email="blake@gmail.com" @hostname="router0">]
```

But when I do Router.count as suggested it still is returning 0

```
1.9.3-p362 :004 > Router.count(:conditions => ["email = ?", "blake@gmail.com"])
=> 0 

1.9.3-p362 :005 > Router.count(:conditions => "email = 'blake@gmail.com'")
=> 0
```

Comment: Does `Router.count` return something else than 0?

Comment: what about  Router.all(:email=>"blake@gmail.com").count ?

Comment: Did you `require 'dm-aggregates'`?

Comment: @morbusg, the `count` method is part of the core, not `dm-aggregates`.

Comment: @Arman: `Model.count(constraints_hash)` with `dm-aggregates` you get a `SELECT COUNT` SQL statement. So the counting is done on the SQL-side, and as such, should perform better.

Answer (score 1):

As **piyush** pointed out, `Router.all(:email=>"blake@gmail.com").count` is the right way. DataMapper doesn't run the actual query before you call one of the "trigger" methods, such as `all`, `first`, `last`. This allows chaining several methods before calling a final `.all` to run the compound query.

In case of `Router.count(:email=>"blake@gmail.com")`, you're running a count on an "empty" DataMapper object, one that's been initialized but whose query hasn't run yet.

Answer (score 1):

You could `require 'dm-aggregates'`, after which you can do

```
Router.count(:email => "blake@gmail.com")
```

and it'll get transformed into

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM routers WHERE "email" = 'blake@gmail.com'
```

(Although you'll get the same statement with `Router.all(:email => "blake@gmail.com").count` with `dm-aggregates`.)